# How to pass the address that contains special character to google map?

Tags: google-maps

As Singapore addresses include "#" and addresses cannot be passed well to google map API.
I am using Java and will retrieve the address from database (MySQL) .Any suggestions are welcome :).

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=614337+Singapore&amp;daddr=109 North Bridge Road #03-39 Funan DigitaLife Mall Singapore 179097" target="_blank" >Get Directions</a>
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding 

It helped me .

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the #?

[directions to 109 North Bridge Road Singapore 179097](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=614337+Singapore&addr2=109%20North%20Bridge%20Road%20Singapore%20179097&geocode=1&geocode=2)

The Places API/library will find that location:
[Places example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=109%20North%20Bridge%20Road%20%2303-39%20Funan%20DigitaLife%20Mall%20Singapore%20179097)

Comment: As I mentioned above , address are retrieved from the database and "#" sign already included in the address format , @geocodezip .

Comment: Retrieve address.  Delete all `#`.  Pass to Google.